# How can i Integrate google login in to my application ? Python

Tags: python, api, google-api, oauth-2.0

I have created an Online Quiz aplication. I have kept simple registration form that if the user is not registered, he will first register himself and then can enter into quiz.

Now I want that If the user doesn't wish to register, he can directly use his google account login and can enter into application.

How do isuppose to do that. I have read the stuff regarding Google API OAuth2.0 API, but not getting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this blog will help you,here s code for enabling google auth.
http://catherinetenajeros.blogspot.in/2013/03/google-loginregistration.html

Here you can find the code that is used with python, Django.

Comment: I am not using the django ?? I have created my app without it !!

Comment: Nope, its not helping me